# Batch processing in Cassandra to copy tables;

Tags: batch-file, cassandra, cql, datastax

I have two tables.Customer_materializedview and Customer_backUp. I want to function such that after every 30 min a batch runs so that table Customer_materializedview gets copied to Customer_backUp. Please notice I have to copy the whole table and not single rows.

```
BEGIN BATCH
COPY events.Customer_materializedview (colm_def,...) TO 'temp.csv'; 

truncate Customer_materializedview;

COPY event.Customer_backUp (colm_def) FROM 'temp.csv';

APPLY BATCH;
```

Comment: This is not linked to [tag:batch-file], so please consider to adapt the tags; perhaps you meant something like [tag:batch-processing]? anyway, read the tag descriptions before adding tags... thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This backup strategy is not safe nor practical. I would suggest reading this document first: https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/operations/ops_backup_restore_c.html

But I will try to answer your question regardless. You could create a scheduled job using tools based on the OS you are using. For example you can schedule a cron job on Linux.

You would need two files. One for cql commands you want to execute on the db and another for actually executing the commands.

First file named "cql" would look like this:

```
BEGIN BATCH

COPY events.Customer_materializedview (colm_def,...) TO 'temp.csv'; 

truncate Customer_materializedview;

COPY event.Customer_backUp (colm_def) FROM 'temp.csv';

APPLY BATCH;
```

Other file named "copy_job.sh":

```
cqlsh <host> --username=<username> --password=<password> --cqlversion=<cqlversion> -f cql
```

Now, if you execute copy_job.sh it would copy your data to backup table.

Comment: Hey Murat... I just want to do it for read purpose because the actual table will have lot of writes. Is it really improper to do that?

Comment: And how do I syncronize it with time?

Comment: If the second table is only for read purpose, then it is definitely improper. Please don't use this strategy.  Cassandra is an incredible index engine. Receiving tons of write requests will not hinder read requests. Backing up data for read purpose will actually cause more load on Cassandra, as it will read all of the data to a file and it will insert it to another table. If you feel that read or write operations are not as fast as you need, you should add new nodes on the cluster and go over your configurations.

Comment: You can use "crontab -e" command and add this line "0 30 * * * * path/to/job"

Answer (score 0):

IMO, you can always write into both the tables.

- events.Customer_materializedview
- event.Customer_backUp

But for the first table, please use appropriate TTL. The data will be deleted automatically.

Does this help?